# searching for tags in current directory only

Tags: c++, vim, tags, ctags

If I have the following structure

```
.
├── main-one
│   ├── main.cpp
│   └── tags
├── main-two
│   ├── main.cpp
│   └── tags
└── tags

2 directories, 5 files
```

and I am in `main.cpp` in the `main-one` folder, suppose I want to search for the tag `print`, and two of them exist, one in each `main.cpp` file.  How can I specify a maximum depth level of `1` to the `:ta print` function so that it only searches in the current working directory?  Maybe an interactive tag search?

I ask this because I am trying to use `ctags` on a larger project and I would like the ability to search for common things like `main` without getting hundreds of results

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `:tag foo` will jump to the first `foo` in your `tags` file, no matter where it is (and where you are) in your project.

Use `:help :tselect` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[lh-tags](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-tags#tags-selection) permits to filter tags results. I haven't implement a filter on the current directory, but it should be possible I guess.